# RDLC code tutorial

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

Is there any RDLC code tutorial or any related documentation?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? There are many great resources on the web. It all depends on what your are looking for and trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486.aspx

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gotreportviewer.com is a simple place to get up to speed on the viewer and RDLC

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SSRS Reports Generation](http://sonalimendis.blogspot.com/2011/07/ssrs-reports-generation.html). This will help you for a head start in RDLC report generation