# Make application using vb.net. That can be print a data from selected database

Tags: vb.net

Hello can anyone help me. How to view data and the data can be printed(the data  will be arrange also while ) using any button using vb.net language. Anyone please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use RDLC with ReportViewer to display reports and print them

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx
- [RDLC code tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739059/rdlc-code-tutorial)